# Trying to use multer but keep getting error cannot parse json at 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, next.js, multer

I am sending an image in form data through api like this:

```
                      <form onSubmit={HandleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
```

```
                           <input
                               type="file"
                               id="imageInput"
                               name="petImage"
                               accept="image/*"
                               onChange={handleImage}
                               style={{ color: "white" }}
                           />
                       </div>
                       <div className="save-button-parent-found">
                           <button type="submit" className="save-button-found">
                               Save & Continue
                           </button>
                       </div>
```

```
                    const HandleSubmit = async (e) => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            console.log("submit pressed");

                            const formData = new FormData();

                            // formData.append("cat", catName);
                            // formData.append("owner", fullName);
                            formData.append("image", image);

                            try {
                                const res = await fetch(
                                    "http://localhost:8080/upload/uploadedData",
                                    {
                                        method: "POST",
                                        headers: {
                                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                        },
                                        body: formData,
                                    }
                                );

                                if (!res.ok) {
                                    const errorMessage = await res.json();
                                    console.error("Error if:", errorMessage.error);
                                    return;
                                }
                                const response = await res.json();
                                console.log("Response message: ", response.message);
```

here is my complete backend code (its not that big)

```
                        const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
                        const express = require("express");
                        const app = express();
                        const cors = require("cors");
                        const PORT = 8080;
                        const multer = require("multer");
                        const path = require("path");
                        const mongoose = require("mongoose");

                        //------MongoDB Initialization------->
                        var mongoDB =
                            "mongodb+srv://@cluster0.a68rgqy.mongodb.net/PetFinder";

                        mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true    });

                        var db = mongoose.connection;

                        db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

                        var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

                        var UploadSchema = new Schema({
                            fullname: String,
                            catName: String,
                            image: String,
                        });

                        var UploadData = mongoose.model("UploadData", UploadSchema, "UploadData");

                        const KEY = "asfasfgasghhgewgwedsgawsdg";

                        app.use(cors());
                        app.use(express.json());
                        app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

                        //-----------------Using multer for image storage---------------

                        const storage = multer.diskStorage({
                            destination: (req, file, cb) => {
                                cb(null, "/Images");
                            },
                            filename: (req, file, cb) => {
                                console.log(file);
                                let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
                                cb(null, Date.now() + ext);
                            },
                        });
                        const upload = multer({ storage });

                        //------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------------------------

                        module.exports = app.post(
                            "/uploadedData",
                            upload.single("petImage"),
                            async (req, res) => {
                                console.log("function called for upload reqest BODY:", req.body);
                                console.log("file: ", req.file);

                                if (!req.body) {
                                    res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid request" });
                                    return;
                                }
                                return res.json({ message: "Checked" });
                                // const { cat, owner, img } = req.body;

                                // console.log("cat: " + cat + " owner: " + owner + "img: " + img);

                                // var dataCreate = new UploadData({
                                //     fullname: owner,
                                //     catName: cat,
                                //     image: imag,
                                // });
                                // try {
                                //     await dataCreate.save();
                                //     res.json({
                                //         message: "Data sent!",
                                //     });
                                // } catch (error) {
                                //     console.error("Error saving data:", error);
                                //     res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
                                // }
                            }
                        );
```

Also here is my folders picture if it helps:

I am trying to create a new folder with stored images but its not working I have tried every way to chnage multer, this is the error:
Server started on port: 8080

```
               SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0
               at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
               at createStrictSyntaxError              (C:\Users\moeez\Desktop\moeez\moeezpetfinder\server\node_modules\body-    parser\lib\types\json.js:160:10)
             at parse (C:\Users\moeez\Desktop\moeez\moeezpetfinder\server\node_modules\body-                          parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
                     at C:\Users\moeez\Desktop\moeez\moeezpetfinder\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:128:18
              at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:202:9)
              at invokeCallback  (C:\Users\moeez\Desktop\moeez\moeezpetfinder\server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:231:16)
              at done (C:\Users\moeez\Desktop\moeez\moeezpetfinder\server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:220:7)
              at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\moeez\Desktop\moeez\moeezpetfinder\server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:280:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
```

I have tried changing multer again and again but to no success